# Android Debug Key React Native

Tags: react-native

Can we generate the new debug key in ~/.android folder? I already deleted the old debug.keystore from android folder and created the new one. Also, I am confused that everywhere is written to get the debug key

keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -dname "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"

~/.android folder is specified.

So, my question is can we generate the new key in project (android/app/debug.keystore) in react native. If we need to generate the new debug key what are the cons and prons.